# First Label within StackLayout wraps to second line when second label is longer than the remaining space

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Within a grid I want to display 2 labels next to each other. A static label of "Reason:" and a bound label that displays the reason description, like so;

```
<StackLayout 
    Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3"
    Spacing="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <Label 
        Text="{i18n:Translate reason}" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
        Style="{StaticResource ListSubItemStyle}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
    <Label 
        Text="{Binding ReasonCodeDescription}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
        Style="{StaticResource ListSubItemStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
</StackLayout>
```

When the ReasonCodeDescription is longer than the space left on the line it causes the "reason" label to wrap to a new line;

[image]

I have tried altering the "spacing", "margin", "padding", "horizontal*" attributes and different "linebreakmode"s to no avail.

I want it to look like the first line albeit with the extra wording truncated;

[image]

Comment: n.b. if I put "nowrap" on the first label the ":" is truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "StartAndExpand" on the **wrong** label. You have told second label to be "greedy" when there is a conflict. Move that to first label:

```cs
<Label Text="{i18n:Translate reason}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
<Label Text=... HorizontOptions="Start"
```

If that doesn't fix, use nested Grid:

```xml
<Grid Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*" />
  <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{i18n:Translate reason}" .. />
  <Label Grid.Column="1" Text.. />
</Grid>
```

Comment: The Start/Expand was left over from me testing numerous different combinations of those options, whoops. I double checked "StartAndExpand" + "Start" and yep, same issue.  Grid works a charm - thank you!